# ASP chart StackedColumn100 add percent symbol (%) on values

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I have this chart (using Chart control build-in on .NET):

[image]

How do I add percent sign (%) behind of all values (for example 44 => 44%, 56 => 56% and so on)

---

**Edit** (after tried `jstreet`'s sugesstions in comment): StackedColumn100 chart so values are already percentages.

Tried `<asp:Series Label="#VAL%">`, got this: (notice that the 0 values are showing up which I don't want, I used these codes to hide those 0 values initially):

```
protected void RequestChart_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //hide label value if zero
            foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series in RequestChart.Series)
            {
                foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point in series.Points)
                {
                    if (point.YValues.Length > 0 && (double)point.YValues.GetValue(0) == 0)
                    {
                        point.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Tried `<asp:Series LabelFormat="P2">`, got this

[image]

Comment: Two ways, depending whether or not your values are percentages already: `<asp:Series Label="#VAL%">` or `<asp:Series LabelFormat="P2">`.

Comment: @jstreet values are already percentages, I tried both of your suggestions and get wierd result as shown after I edit my question

Comment: This is working for me: `LabelFormat="{0}%"`, change {0} to {0.0} or {0.00} depend on how do you want to display those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me: `LabelFormat="{0}%"`, change `{0}` to `{0.0}` or `{0.00}` depend on how do you want to display those values.

BTW, to hide 0 values on the chart, add this Customize event to your chart:

```
protected void RequestChart_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //hide label value if zero
            foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series in RequestChart.Series)
            {
                foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point in series.Points)
                {
                    if (point.YValues.Length > 0 && (double)point.YValues.GetValue(0) == 0)
                    {
                        point.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  So odd that Microsoft didn't just make the percent symbol standard like they do on their pie charts.  Thanks!